# Some aspects of maximum likelihood estimation of GARCH(p,q) model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, garch

I want to fit (by MLE) the GARCH(p, q) model:
\begin{aligned}
Y_t &= \sigma_t \eta_t, \\
\sigma^2_t &= \alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{q} \alpha_i \epsilon_{t-i}^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{p} \beta_i \sigma_{t-i}^2, \\
\eta_t &\overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} N(0,1).
\end{aligned}
To do this, I am first constructing a log-likelihood.

If the vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ represents the model's parameters, and the vector $\mathbf{y}$ represents observed data, I know that $l(\boldsymbol{\theta}; \mathbf{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log\big(f_{Y_i | \mathscr{F}_{i-1}}(y_i)\big)$ where $f_{Y_i | \mathscr{F}_{i-1}}(y_i)$ is the conditional density of $Y_i$ given the process history.

However, I don't know how to specify the conditional distributions of the first $\max(p, q)$ observations in my observed process, since, in these cases, the volatility equation isn't properly defined? Also, how do I estimate the values of $\sigma^2_{t-i}$ to use in the conditional densities?

Comment: This should be available in some textbooks, perhaps Hamilton "Time Series Analysis" or Tsay "Analysis of Financial Time Series", or perhaps in software documentation for, say, Stata, EViews, Matlab or GARCH-capable packages of R.